# How to change default application (GUI doesn't work)

Tags: wine, default-programs, file-association, wps-office

I have both wine ms office 2010 and wps (version 11.1.0.8722), I found that I can't change the default application to wps in any "common office files such as .docx .xlsx . pptx" since it always set ms office as default despite by right clicking the file and changing "property" or "open with". This issue happened  after I installed this newest version of wps, the previous one was fine however it doesn't have pdf reader so I prefer this new one...

Is any way (say terminal) to associated wps with my files?

Comment: You haven't told us what release of Ubuntu you are using, on my release i searched for "Association" in the menu and "File Associations" appeared. This grouped each type of file with the application that opens with it; have you tried this?  I do note it uses MIME type as well as patterns (ie. "*Spreadsheet interchange document*" (MIME) as well as \*.sylk \*.sik  to be linked with LibreOffice Calc for me; maybe your files are giving wrong MIME info (ie. have you used `file` to examine what they report as?))

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04 and there is no "File Association". To use file command it simply says what type is, no info for with which app is associated with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do do this (example for xlsx):

1. Change the default application to WPS (You did it).
2. In your home folder press Ctrl-h to show hidden files.
3. Go to folder .config/ and choose the .mimeapps.list. Open it with your text editor.
4. In section [Default Applications] find string which looks like `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=cxmenu-cxoffice-63f91bab-e37a-473f-87ca-5d0ce0d85e95-3ii0rqp-Excel.desktop` and delete it.
   Don't forget to save the `.mimeapps.list`.
5. Check your default application in Nautilus. It must be WPS

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using Crossover istead wine, so symbols after **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** can varying, but it should contain mentions about wine and Excel.desktop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files from the `/home/youruser/.local/share/mime` folder, leaving only the folders. These files were written by Kingsoft scripts that override system instructions.